# Как перемешать значение полей ```struct```

Tags: c++

У меня есть структрура node, которая отображает узел дерева

```
    int id;
    node* parent;
    std::vector<node> children;
    node(int id, node* parent) {
        this->id = id;
        this->parent = parent;
    }
    node(int data) : node(data,  nullptr){};

    void add_children(const vector<node>& nodes) {
        for (auto node : nodes) {
            children.push_back(node);
        }
    }
};
```

Дан `std::vector<node>` этих узлов. Каким образом я могу перемешать `id` узлов между собой, иначе говоря, перемешать детей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для перемешивания элементов контейнеров есть функция `std::shuffle()`.
Ещё можно вручную менять элементы сколько-то раз между собой с помощью `std::swap()`.